# Asp Mvc Fullcalendar Bussnies Hours Update

Tags: asp.net, fullcalendar

I want to change bussnies hours in Fullcalendar on day change. When user click on next day I want to check for bussnies hours for that day and update dinamiclly. I try to set variable ViewBag.Start and ViewBag.End on MaxTime and MinTime and update it in backend code but nothing happens on calendar. Please help..Thanks!!

Comment: minTime: "@ViewBag.Od",
                maxTime: "@ViewBag.Doo",

Comment: "When user click on next day I want to check for bussnies hours for that day "...businessHours can already be set differently for each day of the week if you wish. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/businessHours